# How to find out the number of blocks in Ganache?

Tags: ganache, truffle-deployment

I have tested a contract on truffle using the command:

```
 truffle test
```

I got following message:

```
D:\Funding4\contracts>truffle test Compiling .\contracts\Funding4.sol... Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol... Compiling .\test\Funding4Test.sol... Compiling truffle/Assert.sol... Compiling truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol...


  Funding4Test
    √ testSettingAnOwnerOfDeployedContract (169ms)


  1 passing (1s)


D:\Funding4\contracts>
```

After the execution, I checked Ganache, it shows me 8 blocks. I can't understand why it has 8 blocks. It has compiled 5 files. How its showing 8 blocks? It should show 5 blocks. Somebody please guide me.

[image: Blocks in Ganachi]

I have attached the picture of Ganache.

Zulfi.

Comment: Can you share your test file? Probably you are making some transactions there, and each transaction gets its own block...

Answer (score 1):

Ganache creates a block on demand, if you send at least one transaction Ganache creates a block. You need to check your test carefully and count all deployments, all (non pure/view) function calls.

For instance blocks 2, 4, 8 are look like function call, based on used gas

**UPDATED**

When you write test in Solidity it becomes complicated to track all transactions, because `truffle` does amount of extra transactions for deployment, migration, hooks, etc.

Transcription:

1. Deploy `Migrations` contract
2. Call `setCompleted()` in `Migrations` contract
3. Deploy `Funding4` contract
4. Call `setCompleted()` in `Migrations` contract
5. Deploy `Assert` contract
6. Deploy contract (not sure about purpose of the contract, looks like proxy with relations to `Migrations` contract and `Funding4` contract)
7. Deploy `TestFunding4` contract
8. Call `testSettingAnOwnerOfDeployedContract()` in `TestFunding4` contract

Comment: My test file is: 'import  "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import  "truffle/Assert.sol";
import  "../contracts/Funding4.sol";

contract Funding4Test {
   function testSettingAnOwnerOfDeployedContract() public{
      Funding4 funding = Funding4(DeployedAddresses.Funding4());
      Assert.equal(funding.owner(), msg.sender, "An owner is different than a deployer");
   }' I think there are 3 functions plus one additional in `Assert.equal(....)`. Please guide me.

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
    contract Funding4{
    address public owner;
    constructor( ) public{
    owner = msg.sender;
       }
    } Okay msg.sender  is a transaction but funding.owner() should not involve any ether. Also I don't know about DeployedAadresses.Funding4() and testSettingAnOwnerOfDeployedContract() if they are transactions or not. Also owner is a variable. Why we have parentheses with it??  Please guide me.

Comment: @zak100 put some details about the question

Comment: Thanks, how you know that 2, 4, 8 are function calls?

Comment: @zak100 based on gas usage